# RenderTargetBitmap - right to left issues

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to capture a control to an image in a right to left WPF window (`FlowDirection="RightToLeft"`).

I get an image with the text direction bad (even if the text is in english) see example : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftd0i.jpg.

Using windows with `FlowDirection="LeftToRight"`, the results are 100%

I'm using this code

```
        Size size = new Size(control.ActualWidth, control.ActualHeight);
        if (size.IsEmpty)
            return ;

        RenderTargetBitmap result = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

        DrawingVisual drawingvisual = new DrawingVisual();
        using (DrawingContext context = drawingvisual.RenderOpen())
        {
            context.DrawRectangle(new VisualBrush(control), null, new Rect(new Point(), size));
            context.Close();
        }

        result.Render(drawingvisual);

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        BitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(result));


        using (var fs = new FileStream(@"c:\test.bmp", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            encoder.Save(fs);
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean `FlowDirection="LeftToRight` the second time?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What are you trying to achieve? The text direction isn't bad, it's right to left as you're asking it to be?

Comment: "The text direction isn't bad" it's not readable...

Comment: Can you post the xaml you are using to initialize the control? Also can you post a link with a example of how it looks with `FlowDirection="LeftToRight"`

Comment: Do you have an actual question, or just this complaint?

Comment: FYI: The statement `if (size.IsEmpty)` will always be false, as (from MSDN) `Do not use this property to test for zero area; a rectangle with zero area is not necessarily the Empty rectangle.` Also it is not necessary to call `context.Close();` as you already created it in a `using` declaration.